# What would be the time complexity for using for and while loops together in a code?

Tags: java, time-complexity

I know using two for loops sums up to O(N^2). Is it same in case of for loop and while loop?

Here is a code snippet

```
 for(int num : nums)
    {
        if(!set.contains(num-1))
        {
            int currNum = num;
            int currStreak = 1;
            
            while(set.contains(currNum+1))
            {
                currNum += 1;
                currStreak += 1;
            }
            longestStreak = Math.max(longestStreak, currStreak);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you think`for` and `while` differ from each other?

Comment: Two `for` loops do not necessarily "sum" up to **O(n^2)**, by the way…

Answer (score 1):

As deHaar wrote. The complexity of two for loops aren't always O(n^2).

for example, for the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n * n; j++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

the complexity is `O(n^3)` because the code execute the 'do something' n^3 times.

note that while and for are technically the same.
the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    //do something
}
```

could be translated to:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 100) {
    //do something
    i++;
}
```

**So in your example:**

let say that m is the longest streak. now the code inside the while loop is running at most m times. now let say n is the amount of numbers. so the code in the for loop is running n times.

in the code inside the while runs m times every time the for lop is running so `m*n` times in total. so the complexity is `O(n*m)`

if the content of `set` is `nums` then the longest possible streak will be with length n. and then you can say the complexity is `O(n^2)`.